# How do I detect if the ON UPDATE event fired with query in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Say I have a query with an ON DUPLICATE stanza:

```
INSERT INTO table (a) VALUES (0)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=1
```

How do I find out, after I've run this query, whether the query performed an insert, or an update?

Comment: I don't know the answer (I've been strugling with that myself, but I couldn't find the solution), but your query makes me wonder why do you use a INSERT IGNORE at the same time as a ON DUPLICATE?

Comment: my understanding is that you have to roll your own solution if you want to know which operation took place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ROW_COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function can discriminate, returning 1 or 2 if the INSERT was "pure" or collided.

Per the docs:

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Example:

```
mysql> create table t (a int not null unique) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into t (a) values (0) on duplicate key update a=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select row_count();
+-------------+
| row_count() |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t (a) values (0) on duplicate key update a=1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select row_count();
+-------------+
| row_count() |
+-------------+
|           2 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra column for the if, and name it as flag (int or tinyint) and set its default to 0, and change query like:

```
INSERT INTO table (a, flag) VALUES (0, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=1;
```

Now if insert is successful, the flag is set to 1 otherwise it's 0.
On a professional level, this flag example is very useful in many ways.

Comment: what do you mean by "On profesional level this flag thing is very usefull"? Also, this would be an utter last resort for me: adding random flags just for this piece of logic.. soon all queries need their own flags, and you'll be left with \infty big tables

Comment: I mean when we have table with millions of data and doing some procedural update and due to any interuption it stoped, then this flag is helpfull to know that where it stoped.                                                                   And in your case one column flag with tinyint is not a big deal if its really necessary to check the status of insert/update. Othervise you can check your table directly to determine any change.

Comment: one field is not a big deal. But one field for one insert is. There might be other inserts, and not to lose any data, they all need their own flags! and what for the next insert? better make another flag so you don't forget what you did yesterday. Soon you'll have 30 flags hanging aroudn because it is really helpful. I'm not saying it is never a userfull thing, but as a default solution to the problem of "was it an insert or an update" it's just not the first thing you should think of, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, i am agree with your opinion, but you asked that  you need to check insert/update status. Btw you can also drop this flag after use. Othervise you can check table directly. If you got any other solution then i am also curious to know it.

Comment: One more thing to say every insert or update never needed a staus report,if yes then its wrong style of programing and flags are for nessesity not for any random habbit.